# How to find the absolute value of an integer in Two's complement in ARM

Tags: assembly, arm, twos-complement, absolute-value

If I have -2 (11111111111111111111111111111110), is there a neat ARM instruction or a series of such that will make it (00000000000000000000000000000010). OR or XOR would not work from what I have tried since I loose the 30th bit.

Thank you

Comment: ARM's negate instruction is `rsb dst, src, #0` (reverse-subtract).  You can `tst` / predicated-`rsb`.  I think that's what C++ compilers will do when inlining / optimizing `std::abs`, but you should try compiling an `abs` function with optimization enabled.

Comment: which arm instruction set?  did you look at NEG?  you do need the compare as shown in the checked answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For finding the absolute value of an integer, use a comparison and a subtraction.

```
@ input in r0
cmp r0, #0          @ is r0 < 0?
rsbmi r0, r0 #0     @ if yes, r0 = 0 - r0
```

Comment: `mvn` a bitwise NOT, ones-complement inversion rather than two's complement.  http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0204j/Cihcdbca.html.  Like I commented, you can use `rsbmi r0, #0`

Comment: @PeterCordes Clearly you are right.  I though for a second that `mvn` stood for “move negated.”  That said, did you get my email?

Comment: I did, thanks for the reminder.  I should have some time to look at that today.

Comment: @PeterCordes I'm looking forwards to your comments!

Comment: Worth noting that if you're using an ARMv7 or ARMv8 device, you will be using the Thumb-2 instruction set which does not include conditional execution of non-branch instructions.  You will need an `it mi` before the `rsbmi`.  Many assemblers will insert this for you, though some will warn because you're getting an instruction you didn't explicitly request.  See https://community.arm.com/processors/b/blog/posts/condition-codes-3-conditional-execution-in-thumb-2